# embedded vimeo background video not scrolling

Tags: iframe, overflow, vimeo

I am using a vimeo video as a background for a div that spans the top of my page. When I have the cursor inside of that div/iframe it won't scroll the page at all. The embed code I'm using:

```
<div class="vimeo-wrapper" style="padding:42.75% 0 0 0;"><iframe 
src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/288403366? 
autoplay=1&loop=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&background=1" 
style="position:absolute;top:-10px;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" 
frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen 
allow="autoplay; fullscreen"></iframe></div>
```

I've tried putting overflow on both the iframe and the vimeo-wrapper div but neither seemd to help.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by putting z-index: -1 on the vimeo-wrapper div

Comment: I tried it and for some reason, the video gets hidden....any other workaround?